# SQL ORDER BY and LIMIT BY do not work as expected

Tags: sql, cs50

I'm running a part of code used for one of CS50's SQL assignments. In this code below: I am trying to list the destination cities from a town and ordering them in the ascending order of their departure times.

Here is the code snippet:

```
SELECT city
FROM airports
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT destination_airport_id
    FROM flights
    WHERE year = 2021 AND month = 7 AND day = 29 AND origin_airport_id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM airports
        WHERE city = "Fiftyville"
    )
    ORDER by hour
)
```

This is the output I get. This ordering is not correct.

```
+---------------+
|     city      |
+---------------+
| Chicago       |
| New York City |
| Boston        |
| Tokyo         |
| San Francisco
```

When I add a LIMIT 1 in the code snippet after     ORDER by hour I get New York City. Shouldnt be Chicago instead?

I'm not sure what mistake I am making and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: The structure of airports table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE airports (
    id INTEGER,
    abbreviation TEXT,
    full_name TEXT,
    city TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The structure of flights table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE flights (
    id INTEGER,
    origin_airport_id INTEGER,
    destination_airport_id INTEGER,
    year INTEGER,
    month INTEGER,
    day INTEGER,
    hour INTEGER,
    minute INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(origin_airport_id) REFERENCES airports(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(destination_airport_id) REFERENCES airports(id)
);
```

Comment: I think the issue is ordering by hour is not good enough, you may have mutliple rows with the same hour then every time you may get different result for same hour, better to put another column in the order by like ``Order By hour, minute``

Comment: Instead of continuing to waste the time of people who are attempting to answer your question only to get it wrong because of missing information, edit your post to provide sample data to populate your tables, and then add the expected output you want to obtain from that data. You should also add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using, because they vary widely in syntax and functionality, and there may be ways to solve the issue that won't work in some of them or will work differently.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the structure (Thank you for the structure in the edit), it looks like the issue in your query is that you are ordering the result of the subquery (`destination_airport_id`) by the hour column, but you want to display the corresponding city in ascending order of departure times. To achieve this, you need to join the flights and airports tables in such a way that you can order the final result by the departure times.

```
SELECT a.city
FROM airports a
JOIN flights f ON a.id = f.destination_airport_id
WHERE f.year = 2021
  AND f.month = 7
  AND f.day = 29
  AND f.origin_airport_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM airports
    WHERE city = "Fiftyville"
  )
ORDER BY f.hour, f.minute;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your structure looks like, but it looks like the issue is with the placement of the `ORDER BY` clause. In your query, the `ORDER BY` clause is inside the subquery that retrieves the `destination_airport_id`. This means that the ordering is being applied to the `destination_airport_id` values, not the final result set of cities.

```
SELECT city
FROM airports
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT destination_airport_id
    FROM flights
    WHERE year = 2021 AND month = 7 AND day = 29 AND origin_airport_id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM airports
        WHERE city = "Fiftyville"
    )
)
ORDER BY hour;
```

Comment: Actually the issue with the above is that hour is not a column in airports so it gives me the no such column: hour. I've updated the question with the structure of the tables.